# Custom Layout that's compatible with Android Studio's drag editing?

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, layout, editor

For a simplest example, with the (deprecated) AbsoluteLayout, you can freely drag the views around. But this following code wont let you:

```
public class TestLayout extends AbsoluteLayout {
    public TestLayout(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
}
```

defining an additional inner class LayoutParams also wont help much

```
public static class LayoutParams extends AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams {

public LayoutParams(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(c, attrs);
}

public LayoutParams(int width, int height, int x, int y) {
    super(width, height,x, y);
}

public LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams source) {
    super(source);
} 
}
```

**GIF:**
[cannot drag-edit a subclass of AbsoluteLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7WEE.gif)
[image]

So how do I make a custom layout that's friendly to Android Studio's **drag-editing** mechanism?

Any help will be appreciated.